# Draw triangle from current mouse position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a category dropdown menu that loads subcategories when the user hovers over a main category.

```
<div class="all-categories">
  <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Category 3</a></li>
  // More categories here
</div>
```

I want to create a safe spot, to avoid unwanted submenu changes, for my dropdown similar to how amazon does it.

[image: a busy cat]
![two muppets][1]

I'm currently tracking the cursor's position when it hovers over `.all-categories` with the following function:

```
function handleMouseMove(event) {
    var eventDoc, doc, body;

    event = event || window.event; // IE-ism

    // If pageX/Y aren't available and clientX/Y are,
    // calculate pageX/Y - logic taken from jQuery.
    // (This is to support old IE)
    if (event.pageX == null && event.clientX != null) {
            eventDoc = (event.target && event.target.ownerDocument) || document;
        doc = eventDoc.documentElement;
        body = eventDoc.body;

        event.pageX = event.clientX +
              (doc && doc.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0) -
              (doc && doc.clientLeft || body && body.clientLeft || 0);
        event.pageY = event.clientY +
              (doc && doc.scrollTop  || body && body.scrollTop  || 0) -
              (doc && doc.clientTop  || body && body.clientTop  || 0 );
    }

    // Use event.pageX / event.pageY here
    console.log(event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  document.querySelector(".all-categories").onmousemove = handleMouseMove;

});
```

Now, how can I go about creating a triangle from my cursor position to the top right and bottom right of the `.all-categories` div?

Any help is greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: I cannot get your purpose about why you want to draw triangle here, if you want to prevent unwanted menu changes when user trying to pass to submenus then imho you should definitely go another way. For example try to set a time delay when showing submenus about 200 or 300 ms. If the cursor gets out earlier than this time then simply cancel it.

Comment: @YavuzTas Thanks for your comment, I've tried that but the user experience suffers because he has to wait a bit for the submenu to show up, this also causes the navigation to not feel fluid.

Comment: If you do not have a burning passion about writing it on your own :) then I found an implementation which looks good and similar to what you want, in case you want to check: [amazonsidebarmanu](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/amazonsidebarmenu.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

you need to create triangle element with `position: absolute` like this

```css
#triangle {
    border-color: yellow blue red green;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 100px 100px 100px 100px ;
    width:0;
    height:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="triangle"></div>
```

Then attach mouse event to the `document` not `.all-categories`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var Triangle, boxCoords, boxWidth, boxHeight;
  boxCoords = $(".all-categories")[0].getBoundingClientRect();
  //console.log(rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, rect.left);
  boxWidth = parseInt(boxCoords.right - boxCoords.left);
  boxHeight = parseInt(boxCoords.bottom - boxCoords.top);
  Triangle = $('#triangle');
  Triangle.css('top', boxCoords.top + 'px');
  
  $(document).on("mousemove", function(event) {
    // if outside the box return
    if (event.pageX < boxCoords.left || event.pageX > boxCoords.right ||
      event.pageY < boxCoords.left || event.pageY > boxCoords.bottom) {
      //Triangle.hide();
      return;
    }

    //Triangle.show();
    var triangleBorder = (event.pageY - boxCoords.top) + 'px ';
    triangleBorder += (boxWidth - (event.pageX - boxCoords.left)) + 'px ';
    triangleBorder += (boxCoords.bottom - event.pageY) + 'px ';
    triangleBorder += (event.pageX - boxCoords.left) + 'px';
    Triangle.css('border-width', triangleBorder);
  });
});
```

```css
html,body {margin: 20px}
.all-categories {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
li {margin: 10px 5px}
#triangle {
  position: absolute;
  border-color: transparent rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.58) transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="all-categories">
  <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Category 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Category 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Category 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Category 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Category 7</a></li>

</div>
<div id="triangle"></div>
```

Comment: That's ok, but if it is meant to be used as a safe spot, updating it on mousemove sounds... weird. It should be generated based on the active menu toggle element, otherwise, it won't save anything bad from happening.